# Trying to extract the value of a field but is showing 0

Tags: php, codeigniter

Trying to display a value of field "roll_no" which has a value of "1FD2020" in php, it is showing 0, when using the below code.

```
 <?php
      if ($template->is_roll_no) {
 ?>
    <td valign="" style="text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;border-right:1px solid #999"><?php echo $student_value['roll_no']; ?></td>
<?php
   }
?>
```

but when trying to extract the value of another field "admission_no", it is returing with "1" value, which is correct in the table. Field properties are same VARCHAR, NULL checked in the table.

Comment: might be due to false error on `$student_value`. try `var_dump` to see the whole variable value

Comment: @zimorok is right, maybe value is null or variable is not set, if using PHP 7 you can use the null or exist coalescing operator ?? to check it - <?php echo $student_value['roll_no'] ?? 'value is empty'; ?> So if value is null or not set you can use some default vale ...

Comment: @zimorok i am a beginner, dont know how to use var_dump. Can you help.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php